# How to save record with multiple field in orchard using IRepository in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

_itemRepository.Create(new ItemRecord { Name = "Royal True Orange", Brand = "Coca Cola", Description = "Royal True Orange in Can", Size = "1", UnitMeasure = "CASE", IsActive = true });

error message 
could not insert: [ERP.Item.Models.ItemRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO ERP_Item_ItemRecord (Name, Description, UnitMeasure, Size, Brand, IsActive) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

I use orchard something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tables in Orchard must have ID field of type int witch is set as a primary key and autoincrement. You can do this manually in migrations with something like this:

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ItemRecord", t => t
            .Column<int>("Id", c => c.PrimaryKey().Identity())
....
```

Or, you can let Orchard handle this by inheriting your `ItemRecord` from `ContentPartRecord` and setting it up in migrations like this:

```
SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ItemRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
....
```